# STREAMS library (openss7?) for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, stream, solaris

I need to port a Solaris application using the XTI/TIL protocols (STREAMS infrastructure, System V) to a Linux system, current target is Ubuntu. But I'm having a really hard time finding what libraries/header files need to be installed to perform a minimal modification port.

I found the OpenSS7 web page, which is rather old and I'm unable to download even the old packages I see there as downloadable. I found also that currently the code is in GitHub, and cloned the repository, but is is already about 3 years old, I cannot compile it (it uses autoconf+autopoint+auto...hell), and the instructions to download compiled packages from the website are not correct, or out-of-date, or both.

Can anyone point me to a way to use this STREAMS infrastructure in Ubuntu, or any other way to download the OpenSS7 binary package?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, in the meanwhile I thought about a way forward, and I think nowadays trying to use a STREAMS in Linux would lead to a dead end at some point. We will switch to a more advanced and modern approach, following the same overall interface but with different libraries and in Python. Thanks, anyway.